# recipes::step_num2factor() leaves last level as NA when baking despite enough levels supplied (MWE supplied)

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes

The *last* category I create with the function `step_num2factor()` creates all levels correctly but the last one. There it fills in an NA.

**MWE**

`test <- tibble(pred = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8), target = c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0))`

looks like this when printed:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
   pred target
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     0      0
2     1      1
3     2      0
4     3      1
5     4      1
6     5      1
7     8      0
```

Doing the recipe steps and comparing results

```
test <- tibble(pred = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8), target = c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0))

my_levels <- c("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "eight")

recipe(target ~ pred, data = test) %>% 
step_num2factor(pred, levels = my_levels, transform = function(x) x + 1) %>% 
prep(training = test) %>% 
bake(new_data = test)
```

Remark: transform because of the level 0 which a factor cannot have. ([source](https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues/436#issuecomment-568122528))

Transformed dataset after prepping and baking

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  pred  target
  <fct>  <dbl>
1 zero       0
2 one        1
3 two        0
4 three      1
5 four       1
6 five       1
7 NA         0
```

**The NA is not supposed to be there. it is supposed to be category "eight". What am I doing wrong?**

Remark: I tried it with "six" as well, as I thought maybe the function only accepts the values in words and not completely randomly named levels, but that wasn't it either.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that your input, levels, and `transform` match up perfectly.
You were correct in using `transform = function(x) x + 1` since you are trying to capture `0`. So when your input is `n` then the `n+1`th value of `levels` is selected.

When your input is `8` then `step_num2factor()` returns the `8+1=9`th value of `levels` which isn't there since it is only of length `7`, resulting in the `NA` you see. The code below should illustrate the issue

```
library(recipes)

my_levels <- c("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "eight")

test <- tibble(pred = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), target = c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0))

recipe(target ~ pred, data = test) %>% 
  step_num2factor(pred, levels = my_levels, transform = function(x) x + 1) %>% 
  prep() %>% 
  bake(new_data = NULL)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   pred  target
#>   <fct>  <dbl>
#> 1 zero       0
#> 2 one        1
#> 3 two        0
#> 4 three      1
#> 5 four       1
#> 6 five       1
#> 7 eight      0
```

To fix your problem, you need to make sure that there are no gaps in `my_levels`

```r
test <- tibble(pred = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8), target = c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0))

my_levels <- c("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", 
               "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten")

recipe(target ~ pred, data = test) %>% 
  step_num2factor(pred, levels = my_levels, transform = function(x) x + 1) %>% 
  prep() %>% 
  bake(new_data = NULL)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   pred  target
#>   <fct>  <dbl>
#> 1 zero       0
#> 2 one        1
#> 3 two        0
#> 4 three      1
#> 5 four       1
#> 6 five       1
#> 7 eight      0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Ah, so value of the transform function serves as the index to access the category in the level vector...; Thank you!